# Which of these subsets of $\mathbb R$ is uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

Which of the following sets are uncountable?

1. $\{x \in\mathbb R:$ integral part of $x$ is $1\}$.
2. $\{x \in\mathbb R: x^2$ is rational$\}$.
3. $\{x\geq 0: \sqrt x$ is rational$\}$.
4. $\{x\geq 0: x + \sqrt x$ is an integer$\}$.

Clearly, 1st option is true. Since it is $[1,2)$

For second option, such set contains all rationals ( which are countably infinite), and all the numbers of the form $\sqrt p$ (also countably infinite), where $p$ is prime.
So, it is not uncountable.

For 3rd option, we can get at most countably infinite such $x$ for which $\sqrt x$ is rational. So, it should be countably infinite.

I'm clueless about 4th.
Any hint would be helpful. And please correct me if my reasonings are wrong about first three options.

Comment: (4) $x$ can't be irrational.

Comment: "For the second option...and all the numbers of the form $\sqrt{p}$ where $p$ is prime."  Your thought process is good, but your explanation is incorrect.  $\sqrt{6}$ when squared will result in a rational number despite $6$ not being prime.  Heck... $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ will also when squared result in a rational number too.

Comment: You can rewrite (2) as $\{\sqrt{r} : r \in \Bbb Q, r \ge 0\}$ and (3) as $\{r^2 : f \in \Bbb Q, r \ge 0\}$, which makes demonstrating their countability obvious..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x + \sqrt x$ is strictly increasing, so for each integer there can be at most one $x$ such that $x+\sqrt x$ is that integer.

Answer (score 1):

Since $4)$ is a subset of algebraic real numbers, it is countable

In more detail: Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x+\sqrt{x}=n$
Then ${(n-x)}^2=x$ and x is algebraic

So if $A_n= \{ x\geq 0:
x+\sqrt{x}=n
\}
$, therefore $A_n$ is a subset of the algebraic real numbers and therefore countable

Hence $
\{x\geq 0,
x+\sqrt{x} $ x is an integer $\}=\cup \{ A_n\}$ and so it is countable.

The same argument applies to $2)$ and $3)$.

Comment: I didn't get, how 4) is a subset of algebraic numbers